# JavaScript round error ToFixed, NumberPrototypeRound

Tags: javascript, rounding

I'm tried many things but I still have a problem,
example: 4.3725 * 350 = 1530.38 but my result is 1530.37 ;/

I tried this:

```
Number.prototype.round = function(places) {
  return +(Math.round(this + "e+" + places)  + "e-" + places);
}
```

and toFixed.

Comment: Do never use string concatenation for arithmetic. This won't work with all numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use toPrecision(). This returns a string which you can just convert back to a Number and round.
The problem was toFixed() rounds numbers like that: 3.65.toFixed(1) => 3.6 
Math.round(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round
Here an example:

```
   function roundTo(number, digits)  {
        var roundHelp = Math.pow(10, digits); // needed to round to correct number of decimals
        number = Number(number.toPrecision(15));
        return Math.round(number * roundHelp)/roundHelp;
        // if you want the exact number of digits use this return statement:
        // return (Math.round(number * roundHelp)/roundHelp).toFixed(digits);
   }
   var x = roundTo(4.3725 * 350, 2);  // x = 1530.38
   var y = roundTo(4.2970 * 535, 2);  // y = 2298.9
```

Comment: Woooow! This is my soultions! Thanks!!! I tried  solve this problem by 3hours. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I have a problem. If number 4.2970 * 535 = 2298,90. But my result is 2298,895 ~ 2298,89. Where is the problem?

Comment: i updated my answer, the function should now round correct for numbers that end with .5

Comment: if u want 2298.90 instead of 2298.9 as result just add another line with .toFixed(digits)

Comment: You are awesome. What are you doing that js i very simple... Thanks again.